# Redirect and Rewrite URLs and Replace Space with Dash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I would like to rewrite/redirect the URLs on my site. Here are the things I want to accomplish:

1. Redirect from www.olddomain.com to www.newdomain.com
2. Rewrite URLs and create clean URLs
3. Disregard certain parameters when creating clean URL
4. Replace empty space %20 with a dash.

Here are some sample URLs on my site and what I would like to rewrite/redirect them to:

www.olddomain.com/events/events.php?location=los%angeles
www.newdomain.com/events/los-angeles

www.olddomain.com/nightclubs/nightclubs.php?location=los%angeles
www.newdomain.com/nightclubs/los-angeles

www.olddomain.com/nightclubs/nightclubDetail.php?venueID=1234&userID=1346
www.newdomain.com/venue/1234

www.olddomain.com/nightclubs/nightclubs.php?cat_type=bars&location=los%angeles
www.newdomain.com/nightclubs/bars/los-angeles

www.olddomain.com/events/events.php?location=los%angeles
www.newdomain.com/events/los-angeles

www.olddomain.com/events/eventsDetail.php?eventID=1234&slid=5678&lid=5432
www.newdomain.com/events/1234

Also, the URLs that are already indexed in google contain location strings like: ?location=los%20angeles

This is how the URLs in my XML sitemap are written.

How do I get google to replace the currently indexed URLs with the new URLs with location string like: ?location=los-angeles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these to the htaccess of the `olddomain.com` should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\?cat_type=(.*)&location=(.*)%(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/%3/%4/%5-%6? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\?venueID=(.*)&userID=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/venue/%4? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\?location=(.*)%(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/%3/%4-%5? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)/(.*)\.php\?eventID=(.*)&slid=(.*)&lid=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/%2/%4? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will I also have to add an 301 redirect for the whole site? for example: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] . And will that affect the other rules that you gave?

Comment: You would add that one after the others.

Comment: Ok so would I also have to create a separate rule for each different page URL? Since I only gave you a few examples of the URLs on my site. There are a few other variations. Should there be a rule for each variation?

Comment: If you want pretty urls then yes, if you are okay with url then no you don't.

Comment: when I use the rules that you provided, it rewrites the URL correctly, but then it gives a 404 error. For example domain.com/events/events.php will get rewritten to domain.com/events but it gives a 404 error.